# Transpiling <XY> language into a custom one

Tags: programming-languages, interpreters

Our company has a legacy assembly-like language with some terrible design choices. I'm pretty sure the language is not going to change, since way too many legacy things might change their behavior which would be obviously unintended.

I'd like to use/find any language which has at least C-like syntax *( or something similar, just make it not exotic, like LISP or so :) )*
Only basic elements are needed, for example:

- functions
- local variables
- basic operators *(bitwise, basic math)*
- Comments

  - NO global variables exists

No OOP or anything special is necessary.
I don't want to actually run that piece of code, I just want to use a decent syntax, which during a "compilation" is converted into that ugly assembly-like *(asm would be at least organized, but it's worse)* language.

What can you recommend me to start looking at? If not necessary I wouldn't like to write my own parser for this. I'm good at C++, but any language is okay if it better suits my needs.

Comment: You'd be looking at either writing an interpreter or writing something that can take an intermediate language and convert it into your assembler.  For example, maybe writing a custom LLVM backend? Then you could compile C to LLVM intermediate code and then translate that.  I'm not really sure how that all works, however.

Comment: Why not just use C?  GCC supports assembly output.

Comment: Isn't it a littlebit overkill? I don't need any generic IR representation, which leads to that any C code can compile into mine, I actually wanted to do some string magic, like adding if-logic and better readable syntax.

By default I thought for example writing the "new" code in LUA, which I parse via C++ then generate the output based on it. Sounds like some hacky solution, that's why I'm asking if anyone has a better idea :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Because it's not assembly, just the syntax itself is similar to it. It's some internal scripting langauge, not a full-blown stuff :)

Comment: I agree with @AlexHart's approach.  LLVM already has support for C, including all of the parsing, lexing and creating an IR representation, so all you would have to do is write the backend that produces your homegrown representation.  LLVM has already done most of the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: See also http://lua-users.org/wiki/LlvmLua

Comment: How is this legacy language processed? Is it compiled? Interpreted? Do you have the source for the compiler/interpreter? (BTW, if you're going to do your own language, the parser is the easy bit...)

Comment: You and several of the commenters are focusing too much on syntax and parsers. Syntax is the least interesting part of a programming language and parsing is mostly a solved problem. The interesting thing about a programming language is its semantics, and that aspect hasn't even been mentioned once, let alone being specified in the question. What are the semantics of your homegrown language. What are the semantics of the language you are looking to replace it? Also, how is your homegrown language implemented? Is it a compiler? If yes, wouldn't it make more sense to build a compiler from the …

Comment: … new language to the language the compiler targets and take the homegrown language out of the picture completely?

Comment: @Mat It's compiled to a bytecode representation. Source is available internally, but not publicly.

Comment: @JörgWMittag The semantics of that language is similar to assembly, but sometimes it seems to be kind of random. There are operator words, like in assembly: xor <something>, lea <...> etc, these can be either simple or very complex. Sometimes (seems to be randomly) they are called via usual function-like parenthesis ( ) like: xor(a, b) and then lea <something> without parenthesis. I'd like to make an upper layer to this, which hides these shitty decisions. Also this langauge by default doesn't have "if" keyword. I'd like to more or less standardize it with a C-like syntax.

Comment: Completely replacing the compiler to a custom one is obviously not an option, since I have to retain the original functionality and just translate between the texts and leave it to the legacy compiler to do its work.

Comment: @original.roland: Everything you listed in your comment is syntax, not semantics.

Comment: "Completely replacing the compiler to a custom one is obviously not an option" – You are writing a compiler anyway. What does it matter whether it outputs your shitty language or the byte code that your shitty compiler outputs?

Comment: @JörgWMittag Well, right, that's actually true, I could simply straight translate it to bytecode. I just wanted to make my layer as lightweight and simple as possible. Understanding how the bytecode is built up (does it have any special stuffs? and so on) has some extra learning curve, but it might completely worth it. Good idea :)

Comment: And now that you've stipulated to byte code output, maybe you can sell a standard programming language.

Answer (score 1):

Watch out that you are now introducing another layer of testing into the mix: testing and debugging compilers can take a lot of effort. It's also another layer of software to maintain, and after you've moved on...

And if integrating with existing software, be prepared for non-standard register use etc.

Possible approaches:

1. Look into using an existing macro processor to improve the assembly programming experience. e.g. m4 (GNU, Unix)
2. Use a simple DSL written in Ruby (which happens to be good for writing domain specific languages) to generate things like configuration tables, etc.
3. Write your own macro processor which will recognize some simple macro directives and expand these with templates. Don't try and be too clever - I don't know your target hardware, but you might not have significant stack space (or, for that matter, a stack). etc. This might rule out nested control structures, local variables, etc.

I assume that the target is some proprietary hardware, so use of the assembler is unavoidable.

If it isn't proprietary hardware, check first that there isn't a C compiler, FORTH interpreter, or (if ancient) a BCPL compiler already available. It's highly likely the manufacturer didn't just have an assembler in their SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to use something like LLVM for your use case. It is an extremely flexible IR, which means you will end up having to implement a bunch of stuff you don't really need, just to get it to work. If you had to be able to run any arbitrary existing C program on your assembly language, *then* it would be worth it.

Parsers aren't really that hard to write. Mostly you have to get past all the computer science jargon. Do a search for recursive descent parsers for the easiest method to understand (in my opinion).  The next easiest method is probably to find a parser combinator library for your language. After that, using a parser generator like [bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/).

The tricky part is taking the Abstract Syntax Tree your parser produces and outputting your target code. Parser tutorials usually have you make an interpreter because it's easier. Once you've gone through those, then made an interpreter for your custom language, you will have the background knowledge to have a better idea of what the next step is.

Comment: This isn't as easy as you think it is. The part of the C language specification that is *just* the syntax is about 150 pages long, and whatever the OP comes up with has to be robust enough to hold up to a company's use.

Comment: @RobertHarvey This answer is spot on. OP is not looking for literally C, just a C-like language. While not trivial, that is really simple. Most of C's syntactic complexity is just that silly syntax for types, which can be avoided entirely. The really difficult part of writing a transpiler isn't the parser, but testing edge cases and generating useful error messages.

Comment: @amon: *[shrug.]* Let's take a home-grown assembly-like scripting language that already has known problems and add a new home-grown, non-standard language on top of it.  Doesn't sound like a recipe for success to me. I like the hubris, but ... yikes.

Comment: @RobertHarvey sounds reasonable, that building a home-grown crappy custom-made layer on another homegrown more crappier layer leads to just having 2 piles of shit instead of one, but my idea is that the second (new) layer will have unified, standardized syntax, but does not have any extra on processing logics. That's entirely left on the legacy layer. So actually this modification can divide the language into two logical parts. Please tell me if my reasoning is wrong somewhere.

Comment: Some food for thought: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2006/09/01/wasabi/ and https://flak.tedunangst.com/post/technical-debt-and-tacking-into-the-wind